# ¿Por qué esta pregunta sin esfuerzo no se cierra como demasiado amplia?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-específica, reportes, votos-de-cierre

Alguien hizo esta pregunta

[¿Qué es un archivo .WSDL? ¿Para qué se utiliza?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286096/que-hacer-con-un-archivo-wsdl)

No hay código relacionado, no habla de herramientas que se usan, habla de algo por lo que el OP ni se toma la molestia de buscar para ver cómo hacer su trabajo (le tiraron eso en el trabajo y estaba viendo qué hacer, parece).

El reporte de cierre que puse fue rechazado porque les pareció que no es demasiado amplia. ¿No es demasiado amplia? La respuesta a esa pregunta es, literalmente, "crear un cliente para consumir el web service". Ni siquiera se habla de cómo hacerlo, en qué lenguaje, con qué IDE, para correrlo sobre cuál servidor o contenedor.

Me parece un pésimo rechazo de flag de cierre.

Comment: Me disculpo, no se que timeline estaba mirando, se ve que vi el timeline equivocado. Ese no es el que vi ayer cuando puse la respuesta.

Comment: De hecho lo primero que indica el documento [ask] es **"Busca, e investiga"**. Al final otro usuario busco en internet https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/working-with-wsdls.html y realizo la traducción que agrego como respuesta...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Por lo que dices en la pregunta, el reporte que hiciste fue para votar para cerrar la pregunta como demasiado amplia. Seguramente el reporte lo hiciste a las 17.30 h, algo después de que se publicaran dos (buenas) respuestas. Dado que no es la primera pregunta del usuario, ese reporte fue el que desencadenó que el sistema metiera la pregunta en la cola de revisión "votos de cierre":

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/169555

Allí estuvo un tiempo y las tres personas que lo revisaron votaron por dejarla abierta. Eso completó la revisión, lo que hizo que tu reporte fuera rechazado automáticamente por el sistema.

Todo esto lo puedes ver a través de la [línea de tiempo de la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/286096/timeline).

---

En cuanto a la pregunta en sí, también yo creo que carece de esfuerzo. Dicho lo cual, es un gustazo ver que en apenas 20 minutos recibió dos respuestas la mar de potentes. Eso me lleva a parar y decir: ¿qué buscamos en este sitio, al fin y al cabo? Contenido útil, ¿no? ¿No será útil tener estas respuestas para todo aquel que tenga dudas iniciales sobre WSDL? Entonces dado esta situación actual, mejor nos esforcemos en limpiar la pregunta, dejarla útil y potente para que la pregunta no se hunda en el mar de las preguntas cerradas (que luego es fácil que terminen borradas).

Comment: La pregunta nunca fue útil y era imposible salvarla. Las respuestas le premiaron la pereza al susodicho, pero eso es discusión de otra pregunta en Meta y esa es una causa ya perdida. Las respuestas son las que le sirven a alguien en el futuro, para algo que no es necesariamente "tener la misma duda que el OP"

Comment: @Alfabravo para centrar el debate: ¿Qué es una pregunta útil para ti? ¿Qué hace que esta en concreto ni lo sea ni pueda serlo?

Comment: Que siga los lineamientos del [cómo preguntar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Y que yo pueda darle una respuesta concreta, no unos lineamientos "en el aire", "supuestos", recomendaciones gaseosas que varían según la plataforma, el lenguaje, el entorno, etc. De nuevo, yo entendí ya que la mayoría acá prefiere dar respuestas buenísimas que cubran todas las bases e ilustren a cualquiera en el tema de la pregunta, casi como wikis, así no resuelvan ni garanticen resolver el problema del OP. Es un "algo de todo esto seguro te sirve"

Comment: @Alfabravo creo que te precipitas a la hora de sacar conclusiones y de desdeñar las opciones legítimas de distintos tipos de usuarios de Stack Overflow, en un debate tan antiguo como la propia plataforma. Esforcémonos primero en entender, las conclusiones siempre pueden esperar.

Comment: SO comenzó hace un montón de tiempo y, después de todo ese tiempo, encontraron que era más fácil y útil mover a la gente a preguntar así como decimos en la wiki:"buscando y esforzándose". En SO original, esa pregunta no vive más de 5 minutos. Las mejoras que hacen en SO original para que sea más "amable" y todo eso van por moderar el lenguaje para que no parezca tosco, no para dejar que pasen las preguntas vagas o perezosas. Esto no era una opción legítima nunca y eso es indefendible, @fedorqui

Comment: @Alfabravo [_no vive más de 5 minutos_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3764681/1983854). Lamento ver una posición tan cerrada, como en otras preguntas anteriores tuyas en este Meta. No olvidemos que el objetivo de [so] es ayudar, los árboles no deberían dejarnos ver el bosque.

Comment: Es una pregunta de hace ocho años (que yo llevo más tiempo allá que acá y créeme que paso más de dos minutos al día viendo qué cierran y qué no). Y lamento que lamentes cualquier cosa, pues si algo es claro es que no necesitamos estar todos de acuerdo con todo para que las cosas funcionen. Yo voy a seguir abogando por no premiar la pereza ajena, es todo.

Comment: vote por dejarla abierta por la respuesta, ya estaba marcada y bien explicada, acostumbro a cuando caen a la cola de revision las que reviso las abro en otra pestaña y leo un poco mas