# Al estar una pregunta cerrada, ¿se debería seguir recibiendo puntaje negativo y comentarios?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos-negativos

Hace ya varios días realicé una pregunta la cual no fue bien recibida por la comunidad , recibí los votos negativos necesarios para cerrarla no tuve problema con esto y la pregunta se cerró. La edité a ver si se podía abrir pero igual siguió cerrada.

¿Es justo que después de recibir los votos negativos necesarios para cerrarla y después de editarla, esta siga recibiendo votos negativos y comentarios sarcásticos de otros usuarios? La pregunta ya tiene respuesta aceptada lo cual no me deja eliminarla para no recibir más votos negativos.
¿Por qué no se cierra total sin posibilidad de comentarios o votos en contra? ¿Cuál es el tope de votos negativos que puede recibir una pregunta? Esto me genera inconformidad ya que a veces es difícil recibir puntuación positiva y el tener esta pregunta así me la baja cada vez que votan en negativo.

Sería bueno que la pregunta cuando llegue a cierta cantidad de votos negativos se bloquee y no deje dar más votos negativos y solo al recibir otra cantidad de votos positivos se habilite para comentarios.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este es mi punto de vista (ni siquiera como mod).

Las ediciones que hiciste a tu pregunta para que fuera reabierta son superfluas. No hiciste nada que valiera la pena como para reabrirla. En si, la pregunta esta igual que al principio.

Ahora vayamos a tus otros puntos (ahora si como mod)

- Si algún comentario te parece inapropiado, puedes reportarlo y nos haremos cargo del mismo según corresponda.
- No hay un tope de votos ni negativos ni positivos. La comunidad juzga cada pregunta según su parecer.
- La pregunta podría protegerse para evitar que usuarios con menos de 10 de reputación pudieran actuar sobre ella. Eso no va a evitar nada.
- No se puede bloquear de ninguna forma ninguna clase de publicación.

Ahora, yendo de vuelta al tema de la pregunta, se te ocurrió enfocarla a la respuesta que te dieron, mas que a la pregunta? sacando un poco de la respuesta, el resto de la respuesta explica como usar una herramienta. O sea, que tampoco es una gran respuesta. Se te ocurrió modificar tu pregunta de forma de mostrar algo de lo investigado (aunque sea después) y luego ingresar tu propia respuesta si mas enfocada a que es lo que aprendiste, con ejemplos y todo?

Comment: Sobre los puntos que comentas: - una pregunta cerrada no puede protegerse. - sí se puede bloquear, lo que impide que se pueda votar (aunque no me parece necesario en este caso, el efecto Meta ya se dio).

Comment: ah no lo deje claro, me referia a si se reabriera asi como esta... gracias @fedorqui por la aclaracion.

Answer (score 6):

Tu pregunta va mas a

> [¿Qué es un archivo .WSDL y como implementarlo en mi proyecto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286096/qu%c3%a9-es-un-archivo-wsdl-y-como-implementarlo-en-mi-proyecto)

Esta pregunta genero polemicas, y un usuario hizo la respectiva pregunta:

> [¿Por qué esta pregunta sin esfuerzo no se cierra como demasiado amplia?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4295/por-qu%c3%a9-esta-pregunta-sin-esfuerzo-no-se-cierra-como-demasiado-amplia)

Como podrás observar el comportamiento como comunidad nos ayudo a debatir que se debe hacer; Otros Usuarios decidieron cerrarla( <sub>eyllanesc, Rubén, Marc, PaperBirdMaster, Juan Pinzón</sub>) , Su basamentos son lógicos, la pregunta es demasiado amplia(y para ser sinceros lo es) abarca muchas tecnologías, y dependiendo el lenguaje de programación y hasta la implementación.

Ahora bien, el recibir puntos negativos de otros usuarios se puede deber a [*Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta*](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2878#2878), ya que al parecer no existe un esfuerzo minimo en la pregunta ademas de que como esta redactada es muy extensa.

---

***¿Que puedes hacer para revertir esos puntos negativos?***, Te propongo dos escenarios

1. Redactar mejor tu pregunta, tratando que sea lo menos extensa posible(una vez redactada entrara a la cola de revisiones y otros usuarios decidirán si es correcto abrirla o no, recuerda que esto depende de 4 usuarios para cerrar ó abrir una pregunta)
2. Eliminar tu Pregunta

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, esa es la pregunta, la cual no puedo eliminar. créeme ya la hubiera eliminado.

Comment: entonces entra al chat, y  habla con un mod  ellos te pueden ayudar!

Comment: no creo que haya que eliminar nada. Las respuestas son útiles y aportan conocimiento al sitio

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO ya leiste a fedorqui! mejora la pregunta!

Comment: @JackNavaRow si señor , en esas estoy

Comment: Tampoco estoy de acuerdo con la sugerencia de eliminar la pregunta, tiene respuestas aprobadas por varios usuarios, sugerir su eliminación es no apreciar su tiempo y esfuerzo, por otro lado la reputación que obtiene por votos positivos es mayor que la que restan los negativos (40 - 14), si la elimina perdería la diferencia.

Comment: @the-breaker, si bien es una opcion , hablando con el OP quiere mejorar la pregunta, el OP esta modificandola para que sea una pregunta buena en el sitio  y se abra nuevamente(Opcion #1)